# Why my checbox is not working? even after setting setState

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Check for each item in a list, i tried other answer given on stackoverflow but none of those worked for me.

here is my code :

```
bool isDone = false;
Checkbox(
      activeColor: CustomColors().primaryColor,
      value: isDone,
      onChanged: (bool val){
        setState(() {
          val = isDone;
        });
      },
    ),
```

Comment: What exactly isnt working?

Comment: I expect `val = isDone` to be the problem. change for 'val' name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to make `isDone` an instance variable of the Widget you are making.

Also, you are setting the state backwards. Try something like this?

```
class SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {

bool isDone;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return (
     ...
     Checkbox(
        activeColor: CustomColors().primaryColor,
        value: isDone,
        onChanged: (bool val){
           setState(() {
              isDone = val;
           });
        },
     )
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just modifiying the wrong value. `isDone` is your value and needs to be changed. Also, make sure your `isDone` is set OUTSIDE of your build function. Otherwise it will be reset on each setState

```
class _RandomImageState extends State<RandomImage> {
  bool isDone = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: (Text('Hello')),
      ),
      body: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.red,
        checkColor: Colors.black,
        value: isDone,
        onChanged: (bool val) {
          setState(() {
            isDone = val;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah my bad, i was setting in build function : D.. thankss